# Newton's Method and Secant Method Convergence proof

Tags: numerical-methods

Show that if the iterates in Newton's method converge to a point $r$ for which $f'(r)\ne0$, then $f(r)=0$. Also establish the same assertion for the secant method.

Hint: For the secant method, the mean-value theorem is useful. This is the case $n=0$ in Taylor's Theorem.

Not sure how to approach this problem for either method. Thanks for any help!

Comment: What are you stuck on, or what have you tried? If you write down the equation for Newton's method and use your assumptions, the result is immediate.

Comment: I'm stuck at $x_{n+1}=r-\frac{f(r)}{f'(r)}$

Comment: looks like you forgot to take the limit on the left side as well ;)

Comment: $lim x_{n+1} = r$ ? I would assume

Comment: Right. $x_{n+1}$ and $x_{n}$ would both have to converge to $r$ (if they converge at all... but we are given that they do!)

Comment: Ah I see, thanks! Any advice for secant method?